# Reset Router Config with Lazy Loaded Modules

Tags: angular

I am building a CMS front end with angular. The main file of the project lazy-loads templates modules.

```js
// app-routing.module
const routes: Routes = [
    path: '**',
    loadChildrend: templateModule, // Defined by env_vars
    data: { env_vars }
]
```

The template module contains a base route that aims to resolve data from the CMS API (e.i: the website url tree).

```js
// template-routing.module
const routes: Routes = [
    path: '',
    resolve: { site_routes: RoutesResolver }, // Performs api calls to get the site routes
    component: DefaultComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '**',
            component: pageLayoutComponent
        },
    ]
]
```

What I want to do is to add the routes retrieved from the api to the templates children routes. To do so, during the ngOnInit in the DefaultComponent, I concat the routes from the api to the already defined wildcard.

```js
const newRoutes: Routes = [...]; // Built dynamically from api data
const wildcardRoute = this.activatedRoute.firstChild.routeConfig;
routes.push(wildcardRoute);

//this.activatedRoute.routeConfig.children = routes;

this.router.resetConfig(???);
```

Unfortunately, since the templateModule is lazy-loaded, the routeConfig is defined at runtime. There is no obvious way to access the routeConfig of the templateModule.

Any idea for this kind of problematic?